# Menu Open & Close on menu button - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a slide out menu, that open an closes on the same a tag. I've put something together but, it runs through the whole animation instead of pausing after opening.

HTML

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="slide-menu">
            <li class="menu-element"><a href="#" id="aboutopen">How tall?</a></li>
            <li class="menu-element"><a href="#book">Books</a></li>
            <li class="menu-element"><a href="weblink" target="_blank">Journal</a></li>
            <li class="menu-element"><a href="#" id="aboutcontact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a id="puller" href="#">Menu</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
  {
   $("#puller").click(function(){
   $(".slide-menu").animate({
   marginLeft: '+=360px'
}, 500);
 });

 $("#puller").click(function(){
   $(".slide-menu").animate({
   marginLeft: '-=360px'
 }, 500);
 });


});
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Left an answer, if it works, please "accept" it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery toggle is a good idea. You can also simply maintain the state of the menu as to slided out already or not and take action like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var slide = false;
   $("#puller").click(function(){

   if(slide){
        $(".slide-menu").animate({marginLeft: '-=360x'}, 500);
        slide = false;
   }else{
       $(".slide-menu").animate({marginLeft: '+=360px'}, 500);
        slide = true
   }
   });

});
```

Comment: Thanks guys, when I test it the menu doesn't open and i get a message "event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead." in chrome inspect element. Do you know what is causing this?

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery Toggle, like so. Simple.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var menu = $('.slide-menu');
    var speed = 500; // set animation speed

    $('#puller').toggle(
        function(){
            menu.animate({
                marginLeft: '+=360px'
            }, speed);
        },
        function(){
            menu.animate({
                marginLeft: '-=360px'
            }, speed);
        }
    );
)};
```

Comment: I don't know if i'm doing something wrong but it doesn't seem to be working. in google chrome inspector it comes up with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

Comment: Are you wrapping your functions in `$(document).ready(function(){}`?

Comment: What jQuery version you using? Type this in console (chrome developer tools).. `$.fn.jquery`

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){

var menu = $('.slide-menu');
var speed = 500; // set animation speed

$('#puller').toggle(
function(){
    menu.animate({
        marginLeft: '+=360px'
    }, speed);
function(){
    menu.animate({
        marginLeft: '-=360px'
    }, speed);
});

});

Comment: Found errors...grab latest version in my answer. That should work

Comment: Nearly there, it say's i'm missing semicolon on the last )};  Do you know where it should be positioned? You can probably tell i'm new to jquery